# What is the meaning and etymology of 蝶よ花よ?

Tags: etymology, definitions

In a book I was reading, a tomboyish character complained about the expectations her parents had of her as their only daughter.  She said:

> 「蝶よ花よと育てたかったらしいんだけど」

EDICT defines 蝶よ花よ as "bringing up (one's daughter) like a princess."  Is this accurate?  What is the etymology of this phrase?

Answer (score 6):

(This is a longer version of my comment on YOU’s answer.)

Let me state an objection to what seems to be a popular theory about the origin of 蝶よ花よ, which YOU also stated as (not main) part of the answer.

As YOU said, a few (actually more than a few) pages claim that the phrase 蝶よ花よ appeared in the form 花や蝶や in [Makura no Sōshi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pillow_Book) (completed in 1002).  However, this claim seems groundless to me.

Some of these pages even quote the poem in Makura no Sōshi which contains the phrase 花や蝶や:

> みな人の花や蝶やといそぐ日もわがこころをば君ぞ知りける (みなひとの はなやちょうやと いそぐひも わがこころをば きみぞしりける)  While everyone cares only about beautiful things such as flowers and butterflies, you and only you care about my heart.

In this quote, 花や蝶や describes two examples of beautiful things.  But I cannot see any connection between this meaning and the phrase 蝶よ花よ which describes how a child is raised with a lot of (or even too much) affection.

So 花や蝶や in the quote above has a different order, a different particle and a different meaning from 蝶よ花よ.  I find it much more reasonable to consider 花や蝶や above as unrelated from the set phrase 蝶よ花よ rather than the same phrase in a different form and usage, unless there is some evidence suggesting otherwise.

As I said, there are many pages stating this as the origin of 蝶よ花よ.  But my gut feeling is that it seems that they copied this claim from somewhere (possibly without thinking).  As is often the case in this kind of discussions in linguistics, the large number of pages claiming something is hardly a measure of reliability of the claim.

Neither [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E8%9D%B6%E3%82%88%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%88&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0) nor [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E8%9D%B6%E3%82%88%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%88&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0) states the origin of the phrase 蝶よ花よ.  I do not have access to a larger dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

According to [JapanKnowledge](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E8%9D%B6%E3%82%88%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%88&fr=dic&stype=prefix) and [Idiom Dictionary](http://www.geocities.jp/kuro_kurogo/ko-jien04/page10.html),

蝶よ花よ usage can be found at 1745 on **Natsumatsuri Naniwakagami** 「夏祭浪花鑑」, a [Bunraku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunraku) play:

> 乳母はコレ此様に、皺も白髪もいとはず、こなたの背長の延るのを、蝶よ花よと楽しみて
>
> A(wet) nurse enjoys to see one's growth like 蝶よ花よ, without noticing oneself wrinkle or white hair.

According to above sentence, your definition about "like a princess" should be correct, and state that could lead to spoil/pamper children.

[Few](http://www.union-net.or.jp/cu-cap/tiyahoya.htm) [pages](http://kotoba.livedoor.biz/archives/50716572.html) says that, possible origin could be from 花や蝶や →　蝶や花や　→　**蝶よ花よ** →　ちやほや
(Or above may be just rumor because there is no official proof for that as Tsuyoshi and Boaz pointed out.)

As as side note, decent word **ちやほや** have similar meaning and normally use on conversation.

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't say 蝶よ花よ originally comes from 蝶や花や. This may be the case, but all the dictionaries say is simply that it's equivalent to 蝶や花や. Besides, the first time this expression appears (in Natsumatsuri Naniwakagami) it appears as 蝶よ花よ.

Comment: @Boaz, True, I also noticed that, but [this](http://kotoba.livedoor.biz/archives/50716572.html) one says `"蝶よ花よという言葉は現代の表現方法であり、元々は「花や蝶や」と言っていました。"` But that post said 花や蝶や not 蝶や花や, so I didn't post it as a reference for origin.

Comment: I've also made a small edit, I hope you don't mind. 浄瑠璃 is not part of the play's name, but probably a reference to it being a 人形浄瑠璃 (Puppet Jōruri), which is another term for Bunraku.

Comment: @Boaz, Thanks a lot. I have no knowledge on that stuff, and I just knew it today.

Comment: @YOU: Hmm... I haven't found that in any dictionary. It seems plausible, but I don't know if there's any proof for that.

Comment: @Boaz, [this](http://www.union-net.or.jp/cu-cap/tiyahoya.htm) one said 花や蝶や is used at 枕草子. Still not official dictionary though.

Comment: @YOU: I found many webpages claiming that the phrase 蝶よ花よ appeared in the form 花や蝶や in the poem みな人の花や蝶やといそぐ日もわがこころをば君ぞ知りける in [Makura no Sōshi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pillow_Book), but this claim seems groundless to me.  It has a different order, a different particle and a _different meaning_ from 蝶よ花よ.  I consider it as a different phrase rather than the same phrase in a different form unless there is an evidence to show otherwise.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, Imm, I see, may be I should have change it to "possible origin" since I also don't have proof that make sense.

Comment: I looked up 蝶よ花よ at Kōjien, which tends to always give out the first appearance of a word or an expression (at least for non-modern words and expressions), and it was still Natsumatsuri Naniwakagami. I might try looking at the huge Nihon Kokugo Daijiten back at our university library, but I it's kinda bothersome. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Second EDIT**

I've finally traced this to a wedding song originated in the city of Shizukuishi(雫石町) in the Iwate prefecture(岩手県):

```
ハァ今日はナァーハーエ
日も良いしナァー
ハァ天気も良いしナァヨー
結びナァーハエー
合せてナァー
ハァヤレヤレ
縁となるナァーヨー

目出度～の　若松様だ
枝も栄える　葉も茂る

蝶よ花よと　育てた娘
今日は他人の　手に渡す
```

Source: http://www.bunka.pref.iwate.jp/seikatsu/minyou/shousai/minyou_001.html

The main part of this song in relation to this phrase being:

> 蝶よ花よと　育てた娘
>   今日は他人の　手に渡す

Where the bride that has been raised with love and care is given to another person.

**EDIT**

I'm still doing some research, but I did find something interesting regarding an alternate explanation. While searching, I found mention of this word related to 「月よ星よ」. Looking up the definition of this:

> この上なく愛したりたたえたりすることのたとえ

Loose Translation: "To love and praise exceedingly"

Which has a similar meaning to 「蝶よ花よ」.

---

While doing some research on this, I found a rather interesting alternative explanation

regarding this when referring to a Chinese origin:

> ほう RT @petite_chate:
>   中国語の「蝶花」を「チャオファオ」と読むのが関係してるかもです。 QT:
>   @marianna_ave:
>   自己レス。「蝶よ花よ」が詰まって、ちやほや　か。 RT
>   @marianna_ave: @hakubi
>   「チヤホヤ」の語源ってなんだろ。

Source: http://twitter.com/#!/hakubi/status/20881151047

In this case referencing it to the Chinese pronunciation of 「蝶花」 as 「チャオフャオ」(cyao fyao). Interestingly the phrase appears to be attributed to ちやほや, Which means to pamper or spoil.

Comment: I saw this claim a lot on the web, too, but is there any authoritative source that claims it?  蝶 and 花 were brought to Japanese as てふ (ちょう) and か, and I cannot see any explanation why they might have been brought as different sounds only in the case of ちやほや.  This makes me suspect that this is yet another groundless claim floating around on the web.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I'm still searching on the official source for this, or the Makura no Sōshi theory. I've already reached out to some faculty members that specialize in East Asian languages to see what I can come up with. Once I find something from an authoritative source, I will update accordingly. For now I will leave this answer here in the event that it helps someone else find an authoritative answer.

Comment: Looking forward to the outcome!

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I'm still researching, but I did notice a page that connected this phrase with 月よ星よ, which looking at the definition it matches more closely, and the format is very similar. Still trying to connect how one lead to the other though.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Indeed, a possible connection between 蝶よ花よ and 月よ星よ is interesting.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I've updated again with a more plausible explanation with origins to a regional wedding song. This song also appears to be in other cities as well. I'm also waiting on Kōjien(広辞苑) to arrive in case it has any other information on it.

Comment: Thanks for the update again.  This is really the same phrase 蝶よ花よ with the same meaning.  Now the question is whether it is earlier than Natsumatsuri Naniwakagami stated in YOU’s answer.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I was able to get ahold of a faculty member from the university of hawaii that specializes in East Asian languages. He agrees that the Makura no Sōshi theory does not seem to hold. Instead he believes that the origin is potentially from Chinese, but needs to consult some references before giving anything definitive. It looks like another commenter has already looked in the Kōjien(広辞苑), and as they noted the 夏祭浪花鑑 reference which was already mentioned (though worded a bit differently) is listed.

Comment: If the phrase 蝶よ花よ has its origin in Chinese, that is very interesting.  A quick search on the web shows that there are several plants whose Chinese names end with 蝶花, but again this fact alone does not tell the origin of the phrase 蝶よ花よ.